# I recommend vs I would recommend

Tags: would

I saw this sentence in comments

> I would recommend going through the Help Center

What is the difference between 'I recommend' vs 'I would recommend'?
Is that only for making sentence more polite?

It can be seen as very easy one to people whose first language is English but in my country, there is no exact elucidations for this.

Many thanks.

Comment: I changed my post from off-topic to on-topic. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right in supposing that it makes the suggestion more polite. There's a hint of "[If you were to ask my advice] I would recommend..."